# Cannot pass the correct value when user Selects an new Option in Dropdown Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a new generic dropdown component for this form. I'm running into an issue where when you go to make a new selection, it sets the new value to the current value again. When I select the desired option a second time, the dropdown will then show the correct option.

Upon inspection I've noticed that when I use event.target.value, it's only returning the current (default) value I set, not the value I'm trying to select. I suspect that this is the issue.

```
function SelectInput  (props) {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
      setSelectedOption(input.currentValue);
    }, [props.currentValue])

    return (
        <select
          name={props.inputName}
          value={selectedOption}
          ref={props.register}
          onChange={e => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}>
          {props.options.map((option, i) => (
            <option value={i+1} key={i}>{option}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
    )
  };
```

If using e.target.value isn't the correct way to get the option the user is trying to select, I'm not sure what is. This field needs to be able to show pre-populated data (or option) but also allow the user to change the value. (In hopefully not two clicks, like it's currently behaving)

Comment: "<select" is missing the ">", maybe that's the problem

Comment: The ending ">" is there at the end of the onChange line.

Comment: Also apologies, as I was writing out the question, I realize the title was incorrect after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems a little strange to me, so I have replaced your input param with standard React props. You don't need the useEffect hook and it works if you take it out:

```
function SelectInput(props) {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(props.defaultVal);

  return (
    <select
      name={input.inputName}
      value={selectedOption}
      ref={input.register}
      onChange={e => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}
    >
      {input.options.map((option, i) => (
        <option value={i + 1} key={i}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SelectInput options={input.options} defaultVal={3} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Possibly the 'currentValue' you were trying to set did not correlate to an option value (e.g. number).

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-input-fn4to

Comment: I've updated my question to use props since most react developers are used to that convention. Also I've added the useEffect because some of the props being passed in are values from the database, which on the components' load aren't available, so useState will insert either undefined or null (I don't remember which). useEffect will update selectedOption with the correct data when the value from the prop is updated (or in my case finally pulled from the backend).